# Personalizar Form::field en Laravel/Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Actualmente estoy creando un formulario de la siguiente forma (pongo una parte):

```
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-3">
                {!! Form::field('first_name', ['label' => 'p', 'placeholder' => 'First Name', 'required' => true]) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-3">
                {!! Form::field('last_name', ['placeholder' => 'Last Name', 'required' => true]) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-3">
                {!! Form::field('email', ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'value' => $email, 'required' => true, 'readonly' => $email]) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 mb-3">
                {!! Form::field('phone', ['placeholder' => 'Phone', 'required' => true]) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Sin embargo, no sé ni tampoco encuentro información sobre cómo personalizar el HTML generado. Por ejemplo, mi idea es personalizar todos los labels (cambiarles el color, agregarles un * de color rojo, cambiarles la fuente de letra, etc) ¿Cómo se puede llevar a cabo esto?

Comment: Laravel 8 ya permite la construcción de formularios con HTML5. Te recomiendo usarlo en lugar de esta sintaxis. Al menos para mí es más cómodo